# Check for live mail log errors when send email

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, vps, exim

I need some help with the command for me to put on my VPS. I want to read the mail log to check for errors so I can to report it to Hotmail. I did a quick Google search and I tried to find the live mail log to check for errors when I send the email.

I am using CentOS 8 and the name of the software I use to send the email is called Exim.

Do you know what command I need to use to check for live mail logs to see if there is error or not when I send the email?

Answer (score 0):

Exim can be configured to log to syslog or separate files.

> The destination for [Exim’s logs](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-log_files.html) is configured by setting `LOG_FILE_PATH`
>   in Local/Makefile or by setting `log_file_path` in the runtime
>   configuration. This latter string is expanded, so it can contain, for
>   example, references to the host name:
>
> ```
> log_file_path = /var/log/$primary_hostname/exim_%slog
> ```

Typical Exim's main log paths are `/var/log/exim_mainlog` or `/var/log/exim/mainlog`, but it could be logging to syslog, too. Check the `log_file_path`.

You don't have a separate "live log" tool, but as usual you can `tail -f /path/to/logfile` to monitor the log in real time.